# extension method overload Queryable.contains

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, search

This is the Error im getting.
This is for a search method.

> Error CS1929  'SiteLocation' does not contain a definition for
>   'Contains' and the best extension method overload
>   'Queryable.Contains(IQueryable, string)' requires a
>   receiver of type 'IQueryable'

```
public ActionResult Index(string projectname)
    {
        var projects = db.Projects.Include(p => p.Engineer).Include(p => 
p.SiteLocation);

        var a = from p in db.Projects.Include(p => p.Engineer).Include(p => 
p.SiteLocation)
                select p;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(projectname))
        {
            //NumberMCP = c.NumberMCP,
            //Engineer = c.Engineer,
            //Plink = c.Plink,
            a = a.Where(c => c.SiteLocation.Contains(projectname));
            a = a.Where(c => c.NumberMCP.Contains(projectname));
            a = a.Where(c => c.nameProject.Contains(projectname));
            //Ptype = c.Ptype,
              //       Pyear = c.Pyear,
                //     SiteLocationID = c.SiteLocationID
                 }


        return View(a.ToList());

    }
```

I think my problem might be this: iqueryable convert int to string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** Were calling INT instead of String

**Resolve:** *Converting type ToString if needed*

```
  a = a.Where(c => c.NumberMCP.Contains(projectname)
                     || c.nameProject.Contains(projectname)
                    || c.Engineer.ToString().Contains(projectname)
                    || c.Plink.Contains(projectname)
                    || c.Pyear.ToString().Contains(projectname)
                    || c.SiteLocation.ToString().Contains(projectname)
                    || c.Ptype.Contains(projectname)
```